# jquery: select closest previous element from child

Tags: jquery

I have a button and I'd like, on click, for it to `scrollIntoView()` to a header tag that comes just before the button (basically 'scroll to top of this section', but without fixed id's), but I'm not sure how to format the selector in order to reference that header. I am working in the `onClick` callback with the button as `event.currentTarget`.

The `button` is inside of a `nav` and is thus not directly following the header, it's roughly as follows:

```
<h5/>
<nav>
    <button/>
</nav>
<this sections content/>
```

There are several of this general pattern in a row, without any sort of seperating containers, so `first-of-type` won't work.

What else do I need to add to my current `$(e.currentTarget)` to select that `<h5>`

Comment: Does the `<h5>` always come immediately before `<nav>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest("nav").prev("h5")
```

`.closest("nav")` goes up to the containing `<nav>` element.

`.prev("h5")` returns the preceding element, as long as it's `<h5>`.

Comment: Wonderful thanks. Not that I currently plan to make any changes, but if either the button was more deeply nested (maybe the nav in a div or something) or if there were other non-h/button elements between the nav and the header, would it be a simple tweak or considerably different?

Comment: The nesting depth is irrelevant. `closest()` will find the closest matching ancestor.

Comment: If there are other elements between `nav` and `h5`, use `prevAll('h5').first()` instead of `prev('h5')`